# How to close menu onNewOptionClick?

Tags: react-select

My Code

```
<Creatable
   name="productType"=
   options = {this.state.productOptions}
   value = {this.state.productType}
   onNewOptionClick = {this.createProductType}
   onChange = {this.handleProductChange}  
 />

createProductType(option) {
    var options = this.state.productOptions;
    var label = option.label.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + option.label.slice(1);
    options.push({
        label: label,
        value: option.value
    })
    this.setState({
        productOptions: options,
        productType: option.value
    })
}
```

Before I click new option:

[image]

After I click new option:

[image]

Desired UI state after clicking new option:

[image]

Did not whether to post this as issues on Github as I am not sure of the exact way of using onNewOptionClick.

Answer (score 6):

I was able to solve this by adding a `ref`

```
ref={input => this.productSelect = input }
```

and then calling it so

```
this.productSelect.select.closeMenu();
```

This (https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/1262) provided the final clue which helped me solve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`closeMenu()` has been [depreciated](https://react-select.com/advanced#methods) in v2 of React-Select. It has been replaced by [`blur()`](https://react-select.com/advanced#methods) The following worked for me:

```
// Assign the ref in your Select object
<Select ref={input => this.selectRef = input } ... />

// Later in your code when you are trying to close the menu
this.selectRef.select.blur();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there have been breaking changes in the library since the first answer, but I had to do this:

```
ref={input => {
  if (input) this.productSelectMenu = input._selectRef.select
}}
```

Then:

```
this.productSelectMenu.closeMenu();
```